# How to add custom column value in quote_item table magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, quoteitem

i have added new custom column in quote_item table. i want to add the value in that custom column by item_id in controller.
i have item_id 16,17,18 of quote 3 and i want to add value in custom column for particular row

[image: i have item_id 16 of quote 3 and i want to add value in custom column for particular row]

Comment: Use InstallSchema class or UpgradeSchema class or for magento 2.3 and above you can use db_schema.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
  /**
   * @package Vendor_Module
  */
  declare(strict_types=1);

  namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

  use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
  use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
  use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

  class Data extends AbstractHelper
  {
      /**
       * @var Session
      */
      private $checkoutSession;

      /**
       * @var QuoteRepository
      */
      private $quoteRepository;
       
      public function __construct(
         Session $checkoutSession,
         QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
      ) {
           $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
           $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
      }
     
      public function addCustomValuetoQuoteItem($cartId) 
      {
         $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
         foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if (your condition) {
               continue;
            }
            $item->setData('custom_column', 'hello');
            $item->save();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's worked for me